# Background color of a list while using range operator

Tags: list, swiftui

Changing the background color for a table is straight forward.

```
struct EmployeeList: View {
    var body: some View {
            List{
                Text("Hello World")
                    .listRowBackground(Color.green)
            }
}
```

This works like you'd expect, and the background color for the cell in the table is green. But this doesn't seem to work if you use a range.

```
struct EmployeeList: View {
    var body: some View {
            List(1..<10){_ in
                Text("Hello World")
                    .listRowBackground(Color.green)
            }
}
```

The background color for the 9 table cells is white.

I've tried variations of this but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help, please?

N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ForEach as below

```
struct EmployeeList: View {
    var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(1..<10) {_ in
                    Text("Hello World")
                        .listRowBackground(Color.green)
                }
            }
    }
}
```